# Photoshop CC Javascript - Remove / Cut a Selection

Tags: javascript, selection, photoshop

In Photoshop CC Javascript - I am I have the following piece of code which aims to delete 4 different selections from my active layer. The selection is correct but I cannot remove or cut the selection out of the activeLayer.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var obj = doc.activeLayer;

var top = [[0, 0], [0, small_indent], [doc_w, small_indent], [doc_w, 0]];
var left = [[0, 0], [0, doc_h], [small_indent, doc_h], [small_indent, 0]];
var right = [[doc_w-small_indent, 0], [doc_w-small_indent, doc_h], [doc_w, doc_h], [doc_w, 0]];
var bottom = [[0, doc_h-small_indent], [0, doc_h], [doc_w, doc_h], [doc_w, doc_h-small_indent]];

var selections = [top, left, right, bottom];

for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    doc.selection.select(selections[i]);
    doc.selection.remove(); 
}
```

But this line `doc.selection.remove();` results in the following error

```
Error 24: doc.selection.remove is not a function.
```

I have also tried

```
doc.selection.cut();
obj.selection.remove();
obj.selection.cut();
```

And they result in the same error.

Comment: I think you want the `clear` method. AFAIK, `remove` cannot be used on selections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Adobe Photoshop CC Javascript Reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf) `Document.Selection` object does not have a `remove` method. Try calling `clear` instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    doc.selection.select(selections[i]);
    doc.selection.clear(); 
}
doc.selection.deselect();
```